# A sequence of random variables which converges in distributon converges "to" some random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables on a probability space $\Omega$, with distribution functions $F_n$. Suppose $F_n \rightarrow F$ in distribution for some distribution function $F$. Must there be a random variable $X$ on $\Omega$ with $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution?

This seems like the sort of result one would want to be true, but I couldn't think of a way to prove it. To do so, one would need to somehow define $X$ "backwards" given its distribution $F$. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "Suppose $F_n \to F$ _in distribution_"? Did you mean "pointwise" instead?

Comment: Yeah, $F_n \rightarrow F$ pointwise, so if $X_n \sim F_n$ and $X\sim F$ then $X_n \rightarrow X$ in distribution.

Comment: I believe the answer is no; I've seen such random variables $X$ referred to as "fictitious" when there does not exist an $X$ defined on $\Omega$ with distribution function $F$. I don't have a reference, though, sorry.

Comment: Chow and Teicher's probability theory book uses the "fictitious random variable" terminology, so you might look there for a counterexample; I don't have access to the book though.

Answer (score 2):

For every distribution function $F$ there exists random variables $X$ such that $F=F_X$. A way to exhibit such a random variable is to set $X=G(U)$ where $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and $G$ is an (extended) inverse of $F$. The function
$$
G:u\mapsto\inf\{x\mid F(x)\geqslant u\}
$$
might do the job but you should check the inequality sign.

**Edit:** For a counterexample, one should consider $\Omega$ such that no uniform random variable $U$ as above exists on $\Omega$. Consider $\Omega=\mathbb N$ with the sigma-algebra $2^\Omega$ and $\mathbb P(\{n\})=p_n$. Call $S\subseteq\mathbb N$ the set $S=\{s(K)\mid K\subseteq\mathbb N\}$ where $s(K)=\sum\limits_{n\in K}p_n$ for $K\subseteq\mathbb N$. Choose $(s_n)\subseteq S$ such that $s_n\to s$. Then $X_n=\mathbb 1_{K_n}$, with $s_n=s(K_n)$, converges in distribution to a Bernoulli random variable $X$ with parameter $s$, hence if $s$ is not in $S$, $X$ cannot be defined on $\Omega$. To complete the proof, one must exhibit $(p_n)$ such that the set $S$ is not closed. At the moment, I do not know if this is possible...

Comment: True, but in the situation I am interested in the probability space $\Omega$ is given. I am trying to show that $\Omega$ admits a random variable $X$ with the distribution $F$, given that it admits a sequence of random variables with the distributions $F_n$.

Comment: As soon as Omega is "large enough" for one uniform random variable to be defined on Omega, the answer is yes, as my post shows. If Omega is smaller, it all depends whether Omega is nevertheless suited so that one can define one random variable distributed like X on Omega. Was that your question?