# On the set of the sub-sums of a given series

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Choose a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$  of nonnegative real numbers with finite sum $x=\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}x_n$ and consider the set $X=\{x_I\mid I\subseteq \mathbb N\}$ where, for every $I\subseteq \mathbb N$,  $x_I=\sum\limits_{n\in I}x_n$. Thus, $X\subseteq[0,x]$.

> **Question:** Can the set $X$ fail to be closed?

A motivation from probability theory is explained [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/331781/6179). Note that $X=[0,x]$ if $x_n=1/2^n$ and that $X\neq [0,x]$ if $x_n=a^n$ for some $a$ in $(0,1/2)$ (yielding measure zero Cantor sets), but that in all these cases $X$ is closed.

Comment: Since $x_{(\cdot)}:2^\Bbb N\to [0,\infty)$ is a finite positive measure, it is interesting whether a more general result hold. For any finite positive measure $\mu$ on a measurable space $(X,\mathfrak B_X)$ its range $\mu(\mathfrak B_X)$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: The downvote boggles the mind.

Comment: @Ilya Endow the sigma-algebra $\mathfrak F$ with the metrics $d(A,B)=\mu(A\Delta B)$ (or rather, the quotient of $\mathfrak F$ by the negligible sets). Is $(\mathfrak F,d)$ a compact metric space?

Comment: @cardinal: Yup.

Comment: @Did: I guess, since $\mu$ is continuous w.r.t. $d$, compactness of $\mathfrak F$ implies the positive answer to the general answer. Sequential compactness, using boundness of $\mu$, perhaps holds indeed - though I don't see it now. Before I left the first comment, I was rather thinking about the following, related problem: if $\lim_n \mu(A_n) = m$, can we assume that $\{A_n\}$ is a monotone sequence? (for example, w.l.o.g. $\{\mu(A_n)\}$ is monotone) I tried to work with $\liminf/\limsup$ but didn't come up with a proof or found counterexamples.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3779) recent paper.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Indeed it seems quite related. I might have a look at it, thanks.

Comment: @cardinal, I agree.

Comment: For the record, **9** users saw fit (for purely mathematical reasons, no doubt) to downvote this question. This site is wonderful...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Consider the compact metric space $(A,d)$ where $A$ is the set of binary sequences with metric $$d(a,b) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ |a_i - b_i|}{2^n}.$$ Define $f:A\to [0,x]$ by $f(a) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x_n.$ Then $f$ is continuous so $f(A)=X$ is compact.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Suppose $a^{(m)}\to a$ and let $\epsilon>0.$ There exists an $N$ such that $\sum_{n>N} x_n < \epsilon.$ So $$| f( a^{(m)} ) - f(a) | < \epsilon+ \sum_{n=1}^N | a^{(m)}_n - a_n | x_n   .$$ Letting $m\to\infty$ gives $\limsup_{m\to\infty} |f(a^{(m)}) - f(a)| \leq \epsilon.$

Comment: @RagibZaman Thanks for this nice answer. Any idea about the more general question asked in a comment?

Comment: @Did I've had no luck showing that space is compact, sorry.

Comment: @RagibZaman: perhaps, [because it's not compact](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/124765/compactness-of-sigma-algebra-for-the-l1-metrics)

Answer (score 16):

The range of an $n$-dimensional vector measure is always closed. See the paper (and references therein)

> P. R. Halmos (1948), [The range of a vector measure](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1948-54-04/S0002-9904-1948-09020-6/S0002-9904-1948-09020-6.pdf), *Bull. Amer. Math. Soc.* **54**, 416–421.

So the set will always be closed.

Comment: Thanks for the (freely available) reference.